# For $\pi$ complete contraction, show that $ \|(\pi(x_1),...,\pi(x_n)) \| \leq \|(x_1,…x_n) \|$

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $X \subset B(H)$ be an operator space and $ \pi : X \to B(K)$ be a complete contraction.

> For $x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in M_{1,n}(X)$, is it obvious that $ \|(\pi(x_1),...,\pi(x_n)) \| \leq \|x \|$. Here all the notations have natural meaning.

I think it should be obvious but I ain't able to see it clearly.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, an operator space is a Banach space together with an isometric embedding into $B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$. Is $\pi$ the isometric embedding?

Comment: @OliverHouse. Edited, thanks.

Comment: Great :) What does it mean for a contraction to be *complete*?

Comment: @OliverHouse: $\pi$ induces a map $\pi_n: M_n(X) \to M_n(B(H))= B(H^n)$ for all $n$. By complete, i basically meant that not just $\pi$, infact each $\pi_n$ is a contraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "obvious" part is, I guess, about being familiar with how things work with matrices of operators.

Let $\tilde x$ be the $n\times n$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix} x\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. We have, writing $\tilde\xi=\begin{bmatrix} \xi_1&\cdots&\xi_n\end{bmatrix}^T$,
\begin{align}
\|\tilde x\|^2
&=\sup\big\{\|\tilde x\,\tilde\xi\|^2:\ \tilde\xi\in H^n\big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\big\{\sum_k\Big\|\sum_j(\tilde x)_{kj}\xi_j\Big\|^2:\ \xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n\in H,\ \sum_j\|\xi_j\|^2=1\big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\big\{\Big\|\sum_jx_j\xi_j\Big\|^2:\ \xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n\in H,\ \sum_j\|\xi_j\|^2=1\big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\|x\|^2.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\|\begin{bmatrix}\pi(x_1)&\cdots&\pi(x_n)\end{bmatrix}\|
&= \left\|\begin{bmatrix}\pi(x_1)&\cdots&\pi(x_n)\\0&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&\cdots&0 \end{bmatrix} \right\|\\[0.3cm]
&=\|\pi^{(n)}(\tilde x)\|\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\|\tilde x\|=\|x\|.
\end{align}

---

My first answer was a more "operator systems" approach, that I left below.

By Wittstock's Theorem we may assume that $\pi$ is defined on all of $B(H)$, completely contractive, and completely positive.

\begin{align}
\|x^*\|^2
&=\sup\big\{\|(x_1^*\xi,\ldots,x_n^*\xi)\|^2:\ \|\xi\|=1\big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\Big\{\Big\langle\Big(\sum_jx_jx_j^*\Big)\xi,\xi\Big\rangle:\ \|\xi\|=1\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\Big\|\sum_jx_jx_j^*\Big\|.
\end{align}

It is an easy exercise that $\|x\|=\|x^*\|$. We also have *Kadison's Inequality*
$$
\pi(a)\pi(a)^*\leq\pi(aa^*),
$$
and that if $0\leq a\leq b$, then $\|a\|\leq\|b\|$.

Now, writing $\tilde\pi(x)=\big(\pi(x_1),\ldots,\pi(x_n)\big)$,
\begin{align}
\|\tilde\pi(x)\|^2
&=\|\tilde\pi(x)^*\|^2=\Big\|\sum_j\pi(x_j)\pi(x_j)^*\Big\|\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\Big\|\sum_j\pi(x_jx_j)^*\Big\|=\Big\|\pi\Big(\sum_jx_jx_j^*\Big)\Big\|\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\Big\|\sum_jx_jx_j^*\Big\|=\|x^*\|^2=\|x\|^2.\\[0.3cm]
\end{align}

Comment: Beautiful answer. Thank you very much Martin!

Comment: +1. I ain’t an expert of operator theory but can’t we take a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ whose first row is $x$ and rest all entries are zero and then use contractivity of $\pi_n$? (In the comments it’s mentioned that each $\pi_n$ is contractive, I assume each $\pi_n$ is defined component wise )

Comment: @ArpitKansal: yes, you can do that. You still need to show that the trivial fact that the norm of such $n\times n$ matrix is the same as the norm of the $1\times n$ matrix $x$. I'm an operator system guy rather than operator space, so I tend to go for positivity :)

Comment: @MartinArgerami: It’s always amazing to see how different branches of Mathematics gives same results using different approaches.  Best,

Comment: @ArpitKansal Why don't you submit this as an alternative answer? It seems like the more elementary approach to me (you don't need Wittstock's theorem, just the definitions of completely contractive maps and elementary properties of operator matrices).

Comment: Dear @MaoWao, Currently I'm traveling so I ain't in position to type an answer. Please feel free to write an answer , using this approach if you're interested. Cheers,

Comment: I have edited that argument in. Thank you guys for noticing.